# On submit, load a html popup file into a div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-events

I am trying to redirect to a contact form on submit to a HTML file which I have made using.

```
header('Location: /dev/thanks.html');
```

However, this loads it to a different page and not to the page that I'm already on.

I already have the jQuery to make a popup for the contact form and information page, which is:

```
$('a.contact , a.contact_footer, a.contact_text').click(function() {
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 600);
    $("#popup").load("/dev/contact.php");
    // Getting the variable's value from a link
    var show = $('#popup').css('display', 'block'),
    popup = $(this).attr('href');

    //Fade in the Popup and add close button
    $(popup).fadeIn(300);
    
    // Add the mask to body
    $('body').append('<div id="mask"></div>');
    $('#mask').fadeIn(300);
    
    return false;
```

On submitting the contact form, I want to load a new file (thanks.html) to replace the popup (contact form) with a thank-you message. Similar to what I'm doing with the jQuery already, but I want it to only implement on submit:

```
<div class="submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</div>
```

What do I need to do to modify my jQuery so it implements on submit instead of on click?

Comment: jQuery's onSubmit method with an AJAX call inside the method to get your html page. works every time.

Comment: Could you give an example please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the submit event to the contact form:

If you use jQuery 1.7+, use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$(document).on("submit", "form#submit_message", function() { 
    $('#popup').load('/dev/thanks.html'); 
    return false; 
});
```

If not, use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live) (or upgrade your jQuery version):

```
//live is old deprecated
$('form#submit_message').live('submit', function() {
    $('#popup').load('/dev/thanks.html');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by add the submit to the form?

Comment: Add the submit event to the contact form and perform the ajax call. I've just tested on your site and it worked! :D

Comment: I just went to the contact form, opened the console and pasted the jQuery that I've posted. Then, clicking on the submit button does the magic you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. but you've slightly confused me, which is not hard. do i just need to add your jquery or do i need to edit this line on the form? 


                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                    </div>

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you didn't do anything else becuase I've updated my Js and it doesn't seem to be loading the thanks.html into the popup but loading it into another window like before.
http://madaxedesign.co.uk/dev/

Comment: Try to put the script after the `$("#popup").load("/dev/contact.php");` or inside an <script> tag inside the popup.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29381/discussion-between-maximus-robert-kenway-lynn-and-falsarella)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that the form will append directly in the "#popup", without that you will have to change the "var popup..." line.

```
$("#popup").on("submit", "form", function(event){
    var popup = $(this).parent();
    var data = $(this).serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "my_url.php",
        data: data
    }).done(function(html){
        popup.html(html);
    });
    return false;
});
```